# Receiving Data source is Closed error using spring-boot 1.2.7 in Tomcat 8 Java 8

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8, tomcat-jdbc

I have a spring boot service using spring-boot 1.2.7 deploying to Tomcat 8 using Java 8. The service runs fine on a fresh reboot of the Tomcat server, but after undeploy and redeploy I get the 'Data source is closed' error.

**UPDATE** this does work on tomcat 7 java 7.
**Hey all, I've created a simple sample application that is getting the error and using an H2 jndi datasource here.
https://github.com/dstrimble/ws_preRatesFilter
I've placed the tomcat config files in the project base dir**

I am using a JNDI datasource on an external Tomcat service, not embedded.

sql.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <util:properties id="preRatesFilterQueriesBean">
        <prop key="GET_SPECIFIC_FILTER_DATA">
            <![CDATA[
                SELECT ...
            ]]>
        </prop>

        <prop key="GET_ALL_FILTER_DATA">
            <![CDATA[
                SELECT ...
            ]]>
        </prop>
    </util:properties>
</beans>
```

WsPreRatesFilterApplication.java

```
@ImportResource({"classpath:sql.xml"})
public class WsPreRatesFilterApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WsPreRatesFilterApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WsPreRatesFilterApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        logger.info("Inside SpringApplicationBuilder configure");
        return application.sources(WsPreRatesFilterApplication.class);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=com.datasource.JBHDB2P
server.context-path=/ws_preRatesFilter
info.app.name=ws_preRatesFilter
info.app.description=Simple Boot Data Service
info.app.version=1.0.0
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>ws_preRatesFilter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>ws_preRatesFilter</name>
    <description>filter rate input before rates called</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>com.ws.preratesfilter.WsPreRatesFilterApplication</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

The error is:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1445347159226,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException",
  "message": "Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed",
  "path": "/ws_preRatesFilter/fetchFilterData"
}
```

The full stack trace is:

```
2015/10/20 08:19:19.216 ERROR o.s.b.c.w.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/fetchFilterData] due to exception [Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed]
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:630) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:722) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:772) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:192) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:199) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.ws.preratesfilter.repository.FilterTableRepositoryImpl.getFilterData(FilterTableRepositoryImpl.java:65) ~[FilterTableRepositoryImpl.class:na]
    at com.ws.preratesfilter.repository.FilterTableRepositoryImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$61dcca46.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717) ~[spring-aop-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653) ~[spring-aop-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.ws.preratesfilter.repository.FilterTableRepositoryImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$63aae081.getFilterData(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.ws.preratesfilter.service.FilterTableServiceImpl.getFilterData(FilterTableServiceImpl.java:30) ~[FilterTableServiceImpl.class:na]
    at com.ws.preratesfilter.controller.FilterTableController.fetchFilterData(FilterTableController.java:34) ~[FilterTableController.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:775) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:299) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:76) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:116) [spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:60) [spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:91) [spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:109) [spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2015) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 82 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Are you doing the lookup yourself or do you let Spring Boot handle this? Can you post your application class.

Comment: @M.Deinum Spring Boot is handling the lookup.  We have it configured in the applilcation.properties file.

Comment: You are absolutely sure that you don't have a lookup for the datasource in the code yourself? Or any other means to make the datasource available again? Because if you do so Spring will auto detect the `close` method and call it on the bean. See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12551?jql=text%20~%20%22jndi%20datasource%22. Spring Boot counteracts this by providing an empty `shutdownMethod` for these beans, but if you override them in a way that becomes useless and close will be called anyway.

Comment: Positive @M.Deinum. I'll add the application class.

Comment: @M.Deinum we are using a NamedParameterJdbcTemplate in our repository class. Could that do the same thing you're mentioning?


@Repository("filterTableRepository")
public class FilterTableRepositoryImpl implements FilterTableRepository {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FilterTableRepositoryImpl.class);

    @Resource(name = "preRatesFilterQueriesBean")
    private Properties sql;

    private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate  namedParameterJdbcTemplate ;

Comment: What is in your `sql.xml`? The template you are using shouldn't be doing that as it is responsible for itself not for references it uses.

Comment: @M.Deinum
 `<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

 <util:properties id="preRatesFilterQueriesBean">
  <prop key="GET_SPECIFIC_FILTER_DATA">
   <![CDATA[
...
   ]]>
  </prop>
 </util:properties>
</beans>`

Comment: @andy-wilkinson Do you know if something changed in Tomcat 8 that would cause the datasource to close.  The issue doesn't happen on Tomcat 7.

Comment: @zachariahyoung Please add the config to the question not as comments. Also add the remark that it works on Tomcat7 . Provide all the information in the question (by modifying it).

Comment: @M.Deinum done, sorry about that.

Comment: Hey all, I've created a simple sample application that is getting the error and using an H2 jndi datasource here.
https://github.com/dstrimble/ws_preRatesFilter
I've placed the tomcat config files in the project base dir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Framework had an issue that [got fixed in the 4.2 release lines](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13022). Basically, if the bean implements `Closeable` its shutdown/close method is invoked even if `destroyMethod` is disabled (as Spring Boot does).

The reason why it works with Tomcat7 and not 8 is probably due to the fact that tomcat8 uses some of new language features (`AutoCloseable`). When  deployed on Tomcat8, the `DataSource` implements this extra interface and due to the bug, the shutdown method is invoked.

You can use Spring Framework `4.2.2.RELEASE` with Spring Boot 1.2.x to benefit from that fix right now. An upgrade to Spring Boot 1.3 will allow you to get that bug fix in a standard fashion.

In the meantime, just add `<spring.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>` since you are using the `spring-boot-starter-parent` in your project.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot update to Spring Framework 4.2.x, another solution is to provide a wrapper to the datasource. Something like

```java
    @Bean
    public DataSource getJndiDataSource() {
        try {
            JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) jndiTemplate.lookup("java:comp/env/"+JNDI_DATASOURCE);
            return new DelegatingDataSource(ds);
        } catch(NamingException e){
            LOG.error("Could not find JNDI data source (java:comp/env/):"+JNDI_DATASOURCE, e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Delegating datasource is not AutoClosable and thus will not be closed by Spring Framework.

Comment: I can confirm this had worked and is a very simple fix.